# How to add field to nested array that looks at another field in the same array item MongoDb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, aggregation-framework

for example i have

```
{
...
 myObjects = [ {nmbr: 1}, {nmbr:2}]
}
```

now I want:

```
{
 ...
 myObjects = [ {nmbr: 1, id: 1}, {nmbr:2, id :2}]
}
```

using:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "myObjects.id": "$myObjects.nmbr"
    }
  }
])
```

has this result

```
{
 ...
 myObjects = [ {nmbr: 1, id_:[1,2]}, {nmbr:2, id:[1,2]}]
}
```

which is not what I expected, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/): Deconstructs `myObjects` array field from the source documents to output a document for each element.
2. `$addFields`: Create `id` property with value `myObject.nmbr` in `myObject` field.
3. `$group`: Group by $id (ObjectId) to combine into `myObjects` array (reverse `$unwind`).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$myObjects"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "myObjects.id": "$myObjects.nmbr"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      "myObjects": {
        $push: "$myObjects"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

> Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "myObjects": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "nmbr": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "nmbr": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e8J-0u87WkK)